# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined; trying to build weather site

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am trying to build a small site that will use openweathermap's api.  The small site will have a zipcode number box and a submit button for searching by zipcode and it will also have a city text box and a submit button for searching by city. Here is what I have so far; I will submit the code and I will also send you to my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snelson26/b65f8uLk/) .

EDIT: The specific...error I am having is - "Uncaught ReferenceError: zipcode is not defined"

EDIT EDIT:  Multiple issues, but the biggest problem was case sensitivity which the answer solved below.

In case the api is relevant, it can be found [here](http://openweathermap.org/current) .

```
<body>
    Zipcode: <input type="number" id="myZip" min="11111" max="99999" value="00000"/>
    <input type="button" value="Search by Zipcode" onclick="getWeatherbyZip()"/>
    <br>
    City: <input type="text" id="myCity" value="Enter city"/>
    <input type="button" value="Search by City" onclick="getWeatherByCity()"/>

    <script>
        event.preventDefault(); 
        function getWeatherbyZip()
        {
            var zipCode = getZip();
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip="+zipcode+",us&appid=fa7d80c48643dfadde2cced1b1be6ca1"+key, false);
            req.send(null);
            console.log(JSON.parse(req.responseText));
        }  
        function getZip() 
        {
            return document.getElementById("myZip").value;
        }

        function getWeatherByCity()
        {
            var city = getCity();
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+",us&appid=fa7d80c48643dfadde2cced1b1be6ca1"+key, false);
            req.send(null);
            console.log(JSON.parse(req.responseText));
        }  
        function getCity() 
        {
            return document.getElementById("myCity").value;
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Adding specifics of the exception that you are getting will improve your question.

Comment: Uncaught  ReferenceError: zipcode is not defined (index):45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive, you declared a mixed case var `zipCode`, but used an all lower case variable in the url string `zipcode`.

Try:

```
function getWeatherbyZip()
        {
            var zipCode = getZip();
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip="+zipCode+",us&appid=fa7d80c48643dfadde2cced1b1be6ca1"+key, false);
            req.send(null);
            console.log(JSON.parse(req.responseText));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the placement of `event.preventDefault();` in your code makes no sense. And also, there is no need to add the keyword `function` when invoking functions. You should have

```
var zipCode = getZip();
var city = getCity();
```

Instead of

```
var zip = function getZip();
var city = function getCity();
```